# C++ pass by reference not changing value

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

Below is the first part of a function meant to analyze a Tic-Tac-Toe board.

The `aboutToWin()` function returns true if a player is "about to win," ie has two in a row. The board is represented such that if player 1 has made a move in that square, the value in the 3x3 matrix will be 1. Player 2 will be -1. If no one has made a move, it will be 0.

The part that I put in this question is the first part, which checks the negative diagonal (ie positions 1, 5, and 9 on the board).

```
bool aboutToWin(int squares[3][3], int& position, bool p1)
{
    // The value you are looking for is 2 for p1 and -2 for p2
    int check = 2;
    if (!p1)
    {
        check = -2;
    }

    // Check negative diagonal
    int sum = 0;
    // Go through negative diagonal
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        sum += squares[i][i];
        // Saves the position of the last checked 0 square
        // If check passes, this will be the winning square
        // If not, it will get handled and overwritten
        if (squares[i][i] == 0)
        {
            // Calculates position from i
            position = 1 + (4 * i);
            std::cout << "\nPosition: " << position << "\n";
        }
    }

    // If this diagonal added to check, stop the function and return now
    if (sum == check)
        return true;

    ...
}
```

This is the code that I'm running from the `main()` function to test this functionality:

```
int p;
std::cout << p;

int a3[3][3] = {{1, 0, 1},
                {0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 1}}; 

std::cout << "\nShould be 1, 5: " << aboutToWin(a3, p, true) << ", " << p;
```

The output is the following:

```
0
Position: 5

Should be true, 5: 1, 0
```

Why is this? I can see that the value gets changed during the function, but it doesn't transfer out of the function.

Comment: Which version of the C++ standard are you compiling against? This is important in this case, as that behavior is not specifically defined until C++17, if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Fureeish In this case, the order of evaluation of the operands of `<<` see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order (in section undefined behavior 2)

Comment: `std::cout << "\nShould be 1, 5: " << aboutToWin(a3, p, true) << ", "; std::cout << p;`

Comment: @Frank I missed that part and deleted the comment accordingly, but thank you very much for responding anyway!

Comment: Note that the return value of `aboutToWin()` is undefined if `sum` is not equal to `check`. You need to add a `return false;` statement at the very end of the function, or else change `if (sum == check) return true;` to `return (sum == check);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau This is only part of the function, it returns false at the very end if all the checks fail like you said

Comment: @Josh: well, what you showed is a complete function (opening braces match closing braces), so the return value is undefined as shown.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I see what you mean, however I just checked the edits and it looks like that final close bracket was added by a user who suggested some formatting improvements. Thanks for the help though, I should add that my code is now working thanks to R Sahu's suggestion

Comment: @Josh: "*that final close bracket was added by a user*" - I fixed it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with using:

```
std::cout << "\nShould be 1, 5: " << aboutToWin(a3, p, true) << ", " << p;
```

is that the order of the evaluation of the arguments is not defined unless you use C++17.

It looks like `p` is evaluated first in your setup before the call to `aboutToWin`.

Separate the calls.

```
auto ret = aboutToWin(a3, p, true);
std::cout << "\nShould be 1, 5: " << ret << ", " << p;
```